# JPA saveAll with unique constraint skipping the db error instead of rollback

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using SpringBoot, JPA and Hiberante.

I have an entity with a unique constraint on multiple fields because I need to avoid to have duplicated items.

I would like to save new element on this table and I need to skip the unique constraint violation: basically I need to save if the element not exists otherwise NOP.

For me could be acceptable create or update approach also.

In theory I think that I could manage the about the unique constraints violated exception and, in case, avoid the automatic rollback but I'm using the `saveAll` JPA repository method because I need to save these objects in bulk.

Is there a way to have this? What are the best practices?

Comment: Just add elements to multi dimensional set and from the set always push to hashmap before you update to database. that should do it without any constraints on the JDBC Side.

Comment: Yes, I implemented a similar approach but I think that this is not thread safe or I need to manage some locks on the transaction to use only this solution: I will manage this logic for a REST api, what's happen, for example, If I will receive multiple requests with a mix of the same items? Probably I need to manage this concurrency issue... this is a reason that I prefer to have a CreateOrUpdate or Create without any constraints errors instead of manage the concurrency.

Comment: then use  thread safe concurrent api's like a Concurrent Hashmap

Comment: Is it possible to make the set of unique columns the primary key? Such a setup will work out of the box with `entityManager.merge()`. It also sounds like those columns are a natural candidate for the PK

Comment: Sorry but I did’t get you.. can you explain me Bette?